# Count cells if contain data from range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

I would like to make a system, that makes a result like below.

The data that I have is the 'Filename' column and the 'Category.
I would like to extract the 'Short Name' (usually the first 2-4 characters of 'Filename') and assign it to the respective 'Long Name'.

Then, I would like to count the files based on which user (Long Name) has made it and how much was made from each category.

The result should look something like the table underneath.

[image: insert picture name here]

The main problem is that there will be new users in the future.

How can it be solved that the counter formula will take the newcomers into the equation?

P.s.: 
I have found this: https://exceljet.net/formula/value-exists-in-a-range

But this is not the thing I need.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. If  you believe its not clear enough comment the anwser to figure out a solution and help you out more.

Comment: @Funtaztic what is the Excel version you are using ??

Comment: 2016. But i already solved it with the help I got here :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to see if it works for you:

Under **Shortname**: `=LEFT(C4;2)` `C4` is the first value under **Filename**

Under **Longname**: `=VLOOKUP(E4;H6:I8;2;FALSE)` `E4` is the **shortname** and `H6:I8` the **legend** which it searches the **shortname** to retrieve the **longname**.

Substitue correctly the cells in the formula and keep in mind that if your excel uses `,` seperator this formula will give an error.

**EDIT**: I forgot to answer your last part regarding the counting:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($D$4:$D$12;D$15;$F$4:$F$12;$C16))
```

`D4:D12` is the range of **Category** and `D15` would be `X` from **Count of Category**

`F4:F12` is the range of **Longname** and `C16` would be the longame from the **Count table**